# Booking Availability

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database field which are 
Appt_Datetime (which is call as DateTime in my table)
Svc_ID (which i call ApptType in my table)

I wanted the system to let the customer know that the datetime for the appt type is not available once someone else has book that slot.I have done a lot of research and trying out different codes but to no avail. I've seen answers on stackoverflow that uses PDO but im not so clear about it hence i'd like something to do with mysql. I have been stuck at with this at least few weeks now. Help

This is my call func:

```
 $datetime = $_POST['DateTime'];
 $appt = $_POST['ApptType'];
```

This is the query i last tried out but still is not working:

```
//Define query
$vquery = "SELECT * FROM Appointment where Appt_DateTime='$datetime' && Svc_ID='$appt'";

//Run Query
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row==1)
{
    echo "Date in not available";
}
else if($row==0)
{
$query = "INSERT INTO Appointment (Client_ID,Svc_ID,Appt_DateTime)
              VALUES ('$_POST[ClientID]','$_POST[ApptType]','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST[DateTime]))."')";
mysql_query($query,$conn);

}
```

Comment: well, even if you don't like it, you should learn PDO or at least mysqli. Your querys are an invitation for [**sql injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: what is error in mysql ?

Comment: Specifically, what issue are you facing? It was not clear from the question. One approach would be to divide the day in to slots of say 15 mins each and store the appointment as a flag. So if that flag is high, that slot is booked. This way you wont have to to date time comparisons. Does this help?

Comment: my mistake.. i have changed the $query to $vquery but i still faced with the same problem. I'm currently using a datetimepicker calendar where the slots are in interval of one hour. @rut2

Comment: the problem i am facing is that i want to the appointment datetime and appointment type to clash so only one customer is able to book for one slot

Comment: Please try to get mysql error by using **mysql_error($conn);**

Comment: That has been added too. I think my if statement has problems as i have already tested out both queries on my myPhpAdmin. @rut2

Comment: please refer my answer, use that if condition instead of yours :-)

Comment: @eternalDreamer the problem i am facing is that i want to the appointment datetime and appointment type to clash so only one customer is able to book for one slot

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
change this to $result = mysql_query($query, $conn); to $result = mysql_query($vquery, $conn);

Comment: thanks but i'm still facing problems in my validation

Answer (score 0):

at the time you are using `$conn` you do not have `$query` it is `$vquery`:

```
$result = mysql_query($vquery, $conn);
```

And as suggested above in comments better use `mysqli or PDO`.

Comment: i've made changes to this and still faced with problems

Answer (score 0):

you can try this condition..

```
//Define query
$vquery = "SELECT * FROM Appointment where Appt_DateTime='$datetime' && Svc_ID='$appt'";

//Run Query
if($result = mysql_query($vquery, $conn)){
//$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if(mysql_num_row($result)>0)
    {
       echo "Date in not available";
    }
    else
    {
        /* $query = "INSERT INTO Appointment (Client_ID,Svc_ID,Appt_DateTime)
          VALUES ('$_POST[ClientID]','$_POST[ApptType]','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST[DateTime]))."')";
        mysql_query($query,$conn); */
        echo "insert";

    }
}else{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers however it doesnt resolve my problem. I'm not too sure what the problem is right now. >.<

Comment: try to debug your project and try to print $results by print_r($result); 

and analyze it. whether select query is working or not

Comment: i've tested both queries and it works fine. however, when i tried printing result it appears as 1. i have no idea why. i'm trying hard to analyse it. @rut2

Comment: ok lets start over we will find solution for sure ;) in which condition are you actually entering from my code? do you entring in "echo 'date is available.' OR do u entering in else condition 'insert query' parst  ???

Comment: i entered your code after my $row = mysql_fetch_assoc statement then else and insert my query which is "INSERT INTO ..." @rut2

Comment: tell me what happen next

Comment: since i have echo"Appt has been booked", it will echo it out and the data goes into the database but it will not validate the dates. meaning to say i am still able to book for the same appt type at the same datetime.

Comment: send me ur code here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66236/booking-availability

Comment: hi @rut2 i can't chat as my reputation is not enough to do so.